# Can files be stored in file manager on simulator?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
func downloadFromStorage(completion: @escaping ([Book]) -> Void) {
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(self.FILE_NAME)
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let books = try jsonDecoder.decode([Book].self, from: jsonData)
            completion(books)
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding array: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion([])
        }
    }
}


func saveToStorage(book: Book, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.downloadFromStorage() { (downloadedBooks) in
        var books = downloadedBooks
        books.removeAll { $0.id == book.id }
        if (books.count > 10) {
            books.removeLast()
        }
        books.insert(book, at: 0)
        
        self.saveAudio(book: book)
        self.saveVideo(book: book)
        
        let video = "sumizeit-video-" + String(book.id) + ".mp4"
        book.setVideo(video: video)
        book.setMediaUrl(mediaUrl: "sumizeit-audio-" + String(book.id) + ".mp3")
        
        self.items = books
        MUser.sharedInstance.downloadedItems = self.items
        
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        do {
            let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(books)
            if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
                let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(self.FILE_NAME)
                try jsonData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                completion()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error encoding array: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to save to storage and the download from storage, I get empty data. Meaning the storage is empty. Can files be downloaded or saved to file manager in IOS simulator?

I get the error The data couldn’t be read because it is missing. from downloadFromStorage

Comment: Why does `saveToStorage` first call `downloadFromStorage`?

Comment: To add the book to the array of books that are already there

Comment: OK, I see now. Before you ever save anything the first time, of course there is no data stored anywhere. So the first time you ever call `saveToStorage`, `downloadFromStorage` won't find anything. That's why you get no data. But then `saveToStorage` will add the new book and save it. So the 2nd time you call `savetoStorage`, `downloadFromStorage` should find that existing data. Is this what is happening? And yes, saving files to the Documents folder works in a simulator.